# How can I add two background images with Elementor?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

### My Problem

I'm trying to set two background images to my wordpress page I create with Elementor. I can do that easily if I set two background images to the body. But my client wants to edit one of these background images themselves in Elementor. The problem is that Elementor only lets me add one background image (Elementor adds it to the body).

How can I set one background image via Elementor and one via css for the whole page?

I was thinking that I need another div just inside the start and the end of the body tag. But how can I add that in elementor?

This is how I do it right now with custom css. It works, but then the background image is not changeable with Elementor.

```
body {
 background-image: url(image2.svg),
      url(image1.jpg);
}
```

Comment: You could use custom fields to store the second background url https://elementor.com/blog/wordpress-custom-fields/ But then you need to extract that value from PHP

Comment: unless you use Elementor PRO, which allows you to  «"dynamically” display content from custom fields in your Elementor designs»

Comment: Oh I do use pro. That sounds good I'll have a look! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to set the the image on the html tag via css then use Elementor to set the other since it will allow you to do placement etc.

Comment: Yes that's a good idea! I kind of had it in my head that that's bad practice but if it works that should be okay.

Comment: Not 100% ideal but the one offs and if it works within the system you need to or have to work with.

Answer (score -2):

Why are you even using Elementor? I'm sure you can't do it with it. Just tell your client that they can't change it in Elementor.

Otherwise you need to add a custom div-Element after your body and right at the end of it. But if you use elementor you can't do any of that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).